# Any way to prevent "select_node.jstree" from being called when node closed in the jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jstree

When you open nodes, it's fine.  The "select_node.jstree" is not called.  However, when you select a node and then close its' parent, jstree fires "select_node.jstree" for that parent node for some strange reason.  Is there any way around this or is that just a flaw with jstree?  I'd appreciate the help!  Here's my code:

```
        $("#RequirementsTree")
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
            ReqNode = data.rslt.obj;
            $("#req_tree_modal").dialog({ height: 400, width: 600, modal: true, closeOnEscape: true, resizable: false, show: "blind" });
            $("#RMSDoc_ParentNodeID").val(data.rslt.obj.attr("id").substring(4));
            if(is_requirement_node(data))
            {
                dispEditRequirementView();

                var ReqCheck = data.rslt.obj.attr("name");

                @* This is a REQUIREMENT *@
                if(ReqCheck == "requirement")
                {
                    // Ajax call to Server with requirement id passed in
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Content("~/RMS/getRequirementStateByID")',
                        data: {
                            ReqID : data.rslt.obj.attr("id").substring(4)
                        },
                        success: function(new_data) {
                            if(new_data == 1){
                                $("#RMSDoc_ReqEnabled").attr("checked", "checked");
                                $("#RMSDoc_ReqEnabled").val("true");
                            }
                            else if(new_data == 0) {
                                $("#RMSDoc_ReqEnabled").removeAttr("checked");
                                $("#RMSDoc_ReqEnabled").val("false");
                            }
                        }   
                    });

                    $("#RMSDoc_RBSRequirement_RequirementsId").val(data.rslt.obj.attr("id").substring(4));
                    $("#RMSDoc_RBSRequirement_RequirementsText").val($.trim(data.rslt.obj.text()));
                    $("#ExistingTreeSubmit").val("@Model.RMSDoc.RMSEditReqButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc");

                }
                else {
                    alert("Requirement node select error");
                }
            }
            @* This is a TREE BRANCH *@
            else
            {
                dispAddRequirementView();
                $("#RMSDoc_TreeBranch_Text").val($.trim($('.jstree-clicked').text()));
                $("#RMSDoc_TreeBranch_id").val(data.rslt.obj.attr("id").substring(4));
                $("#RMSDoc_TreeBranch_Level").val(data.rslt.obj.attr("name").substring(7));
                $("#RMSDoc_RBSRequirement_RequirementsText").val("");
                $("#ExistingTreeSubmit").val("@Model.RMSDoc.RMSCreateReqButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc");
            }
     })
```

Comment: Same question here.  I'm thinking about directly handling the click for the internal <a instead of handling the select_node.jstree.  If that works I'll re-post

Answer (score 1):

Update:
I found a way to get it to work within the plugin, add the following to the "ui" config section:

```
        "ui": {
            "select_limit": 1,
            "selected_parent_close":false
        },
```

I believe what was happening is that when a sub-node was selected, collapsing the parent node would cause the parent node to be selected, triggering the event.

---------- Original Answer ---------------------

I'm not sure on the answer working within the bounds of the plugin.  But I did find a work-around.

I added a class to each of the anchor () tags inside the tree "an".

```
<li class='jstree-closed' id="phtml_3" rel="folder">
    <a href="#" class="an">test node 2</a>
</li>
```

Then I wired JQuery to look for anchors with this class, and handled my click that way.

```
instance.on("click", "a.an", function (e) {
    alert("click");
});
```

I still need to add code to find the ID from the parent-container, not optimal... but I don't have to compete with the collapse anymore for my click.